# Search in list of objects

Tags: c#

I have a list with Customer objects and I'm trying to search for a name in each object. In the Customer object there is a properties, ContactData, that return a Contact object. And inside the Contact object I have a method that  returns a string of a name. It is that name I'm trying to compare with, but it's not working properly, because I get a hit every time, despite I search for a name that don't exist in any of the Customer object. The code I'm using:

```
foreach (Customer name in m_customers)
{
      if (name.ContactData.FullName == "Anna") 
      {
          MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Yes"), "Test!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); // Just for testing  
      }
}
```

I have also tested to use a simple for loop, but I get the same result. I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing and would preciate some help! Thanks!

Comment: Insert a simple `console.writeline` call in your foreach loop to print ContactData.FullName for every item in the loop. Your variable naming is confusing, you probably want `foreach (Customer customer in m_customers)`

Comment: Have you verified that `m_customers` contains a list of unique objects?

Comment: Could you explain that, ChrisF?

Comment: Use the debugger (or even a simple `Console.WriteLine`) to check that each record in `m_customers` is unique and points to a unique `ContactData` object. It sound like all your data points to the same contact "Anna".

Comment: I have tested to use Console.WriteLine, but I guess that isn't working when I'm using a Form GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it might be that the 'FullName' is somehow being set to "Anna" for all customers somewhere in your code, or in the database, or in the stored proc...

```
foreach (Customer name in m_customers) 
{ 
    if(name.ContactData != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(name.ContactData.FullName);

    if (name.ContactData.FullName == "Anna")  
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Yes"), "Test!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); // Just for testing   
    } 
}
```

If that's the case, do a global search for the keyword 'Anna' and see what pops up.

The other possibility is that you're not creating a new ContactData object with each Customer and simply reusing a variable.  This might be updating all Customers with the SAME ContactData object because a pointer is being used.  Instead, with each Customer, create a brand new ContactData object instead.

If these two possibilities don't help, you'll have to post more code to troubleshoot.

Comment: I get a red line under the WriteLine in your code! Despite I'm using using System.Diagnostics; I have also used a messagebox to show the name in each object, and they are all different and correct

Comment: Oops... sorry, my bad.  It's System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine

Comment: So.. if you take your same code and drop in "John.Doe.Should.Not.Exist", the MessageBox fires??

Comment: Does this work? I'm using a GUI made of a form. I guess then I can't show text in VisualStudio? It might be as you write in the beginning that FullName is being set to the name I'm searching fore, but how can I avoid that?

Comment: You need to run your app in debug mode (within the IDE) to see the debug output.

Comment: It seems like it's working now! I tested to use a simple for loop again and used Equals instead of just ==. When I search, is there a way to make the search not case sensative? Both Anna and anna?

Comment: Yes, change it to string.Equals(name.ContactData.FullName, "Anna", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)